# check if string contains special characters in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I want to check if a password contains special characters. I have googled for a few examples but cant find that addresses my problem. How do I do it? Here is how I am trying it so far;

```
elif not re.match("^[~!@#$%^&*()_+{}":;']+$",password)
        print "Invalid entry."
        continue
```

My string is password.

Comment: and you're not getting a syntax error from that?

Answer (score 8):

You don't need a regex for this.  Try:

```
elif set('[~!@#$%^&*()_+{}":;\']+$').intersection(password):
    print "Invalid entry."
```

The quotation mark has been escaped in the string.  What this does is create a set containing all your invalid characters, then take the intersection of it and `password` (in other words, a set containing all unique characters that exist in both the set and the password string).  If there are no matches, the resulting set will be empty, and thus evaluate as `False`, otherwise it will evaluate as `True` and print the message.

Answer (score 0):

Several of the symbols in your special characters string have special meaning in regexes, and must be escaped. You are getting the syntax error because you included `"` in the middle of a string delineated by double quotes, so Python finishes processing the string there, then chokes on the garbage it sees afterwards. Try this:

```
elif not re.match(r"[~\!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\+{}\":;'\[\]]", password):
    print "Invalid entry"
    continue
```

I used a raw string literal, which you should always use in regexes. I escaped the characters that needed to be escaped, and simplified your expression a bit, as the beginning `^` and end `$` of string markers aren't necessary - as soon as 1 match is made, it will return True, and will skip the following code.

When in doubt, escape :)

Comment: Don't you want `elif` rather than `elif not`? Seems like you're printing "Invalid entry" if the password does NOT match the regex.

Comment: @celeritas yes, that's what you want to happen. If the match works, the password contains at least 1 special character, and it is therefore "good". If the regex matches `password`, it's value will be `True`. You need to negate that to run the indented code. Think about it...

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the OP wanted to make sure the password did NOT contain special character(s).

Comment: You don't need all of those backslashes. Most special characters lose their special powers inside square brackets.

Comment: @Bryan true, but as I said, when in doubt, escape! I'm still getting comfortable with regexes, and don't quite have all the rules memorized yet.